# Mysql 5.1 view performance

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know if the usage of Views in Mysql (version 5.1.57) offers better performance than doing always the same query directly to the db?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

A view is just a macro that expands into the full query. 
 
A view doesn't offer any magical performance boost